# onpopstate handler - ajax back button

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, google-chrome

I'm using pushState to create meaningful urls for ajax content on my site. I want to refresh the ajax content when the user hits the forward or back buttons. I'm having problems however as chrome (correctly) impliments onpopstate on both 'history traversal' (forward/back buttons) and 'the end' (page load). I'd like to create an onpopstate handler that differentiates between page load and history  traversal, as I don't want to refresh my ajax content if it's already just been loaded successfully. Can anybody help me with differentiating between the two?

```
window.onpopstate = function (event) {
    // If : Forward/back button pressed
        // Reload any ajax content with new variables
    // Else : Page load complete
        // Do nothing - content already loaded and correct
}
```

See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=63040 for more details on chrome and onpopstate.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way would be to initialize a variable to false on page load, and then on your popstate event, check that variable. If it's still false, set it to true and do nothing. From then on all of your other popstate events should be only from back/forward events.

```
var loaded = false;

window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    if (!loaded) {
        loaded = true;
        return;
    } else {
        // run your stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: What about in browsers like Firefox where onpopstate is not called on load? This would mean that the first legitimate history traversal pop would be ignored?

Comment: I am doing it like this for cross browser...but i don't know exactly what browsers should be targetted...Opera, firefox, safari, and chrome work fine with the following.

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
     if (!loaded && $.browser.webkit) {

Comment: It fails on Firefox. To fix the issue, fire `if (!loaded) { loaded = true; return; }` onclick/tap the link.

Answer (score 3):

The object passed to the `onpopstate` function will have a `state` member, which will be `null` on the page load, so you could do something like this:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  if(event && event.state) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I am confused about this; I'm clicking around on some elements that have the click event binded, and they are all triggering the `popstate` event, and they all have `state: null`.

Comment: Use `history.pushState({'url':url},title,url);` with `url` being the URL of the loaded content (look up JSON) and then you can access this via: `window.onpopstate = function(e) {alert(JSON.stringify(e.state).url);}`.

Answer (score 1):

//example: http://www.nseri.com/news/5536

```
window.onpopstate = function(e) {
     var count = String(location.pathname).split('/').length;
     if (count<4) {
          location.href = location.href;
     }else {
          $.ajaxLoad(location.pathname);
     }
}
```