# HTML5 History API - Do not fire window.onpopstate event at the first page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, browser-history

With HTML5 History API, I created something like below:

```
(function (d, w) {

    $(function () {

        $("#indicator").hide();

        if (typeof history.pushState !== 'undefined') { 

            $("#citylinks a").click(function (e) {
                history.pushState({ path: this.href }, '', this.href);
                act(this.href);
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            w.onpopstate = function (event) {
                act(d.location);
            };
        }

        function act(location) {

            $("#results").hide();
            $("#indicator").show();

            $.getJSON(location, function (data) {

                $("#results").html(data.result);
                $("#results").fadeIn();

                $("#indicator").hide();
            });
        }

    });

})(document, window);
```

The complete code is here:

https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/MvcMiracleWorker/commit/7c511f20678bbfe15462909c794eb323ce615372#diff-3

The problem I have here is that I do not want to fire the `w.onpopstate` event at the first time page comes from the server.

The reason I would like to do this is that I would like to fill the page at the server side and I do not want client side code to do that. If I remove `w.onpopstate` event, I won't be able to catch `history.go()` events.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple approach would be this:

```
w.onpopstate = function () {
    w.onpopstate = function (event) {
        act(d.location);
    }
}
```

This means that the first time the `onpopstate` event fires, your function is set to the event handler (replacing the current handler), effectively creating a *noop* for when the event runs on page load.

Comment: Nice solution. One thing is that it runs on every `windows.onpopstate` event. I tried to prevent that (by checking the `window.onpopstate` event if `null` or `undefined`) but couldn't get it work.

Comment: That's a bit of a hack-y solution.  You could try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11453389/191551 instead.

Comment: @Ryan: perhaps it's hacky, but I don't really see it. If anything, it's more efficient because it doesn't require the additional checks of the example you linked to. Of course, we're talking microseconds and it's not important, but on the flip-side I don't see anything wrong with using the technique. It's something I've seen employed many times in many scripts that I am, unfortunately, unable to recall at this moment in time :-p

Comment: Will this work in firefox considering it does not fire onpopstate for pageload, so the function would be first set wrongly on a valid .back()/.forward() event ?

Comment: @LaserBeak: if that's truly the case then, yes, this code would have an issue in Firefox.  Since the OP never said which browser exhibited this problem and he subsequently marked this answer as correct, I assumed that all browsers shared the same behaviour.  If this isn't the case, one or more of them might have a bug.

Comment: Actually looks like Firefox is the only browser currently following the standard. Chrome and Safari are firing `onpopstate` on first page load, hence they're out of the standard.

Comment: The bug has been fixed on Chrome 34 canary build.