# How to tell the difference between 'real' and 'virtual' onpopstate events

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history, html5-history

I'm building a tool that uses AJAX and `pushState`/`replaceState` on top of a non-javascript fallback (http://biologos.org/resources/find). Basically, it's a search tool that returns a list of real HTML links (clicking a link takes you out of the tool).

I am using `onpopstate` so the user can navigate through their query history created by `pushState`. This event *also* fires when navigating back from a real link (one **NOT** created with `pushState` but by actual browser navigation). I don't want it to fire here.

So here's my question: how can I tell the difference between a `onpopstate` event coming from a `pushState` history item, vs one that comes from real navigation?

I want to do something like this:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event){
  if(event.realClick) return;

  // otherwise do something

}
```

I've tried [onpopstate handler - ajax back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257819/onpopstate-handler-ajax-back-button) but with no luck :(

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
A problem here is the way different browsers handle the `onpopstate` event. Here's what seems to be happening:

Chrome

- Fires `onpopstate` on both *real* and *virtual* events
- Actually re-runs javascript (so setting `loaded=false` will actually test false)
- The solution in the above link actually works!

Firefox

- Only fires `onpopstate` on *virtual* events
- Actually re-runs javascript (so setting `loaded=false` will actually test false)
- For the linked solution to actually work, `loaded` needs to be set true on page load, which breaks Chrome!

Safari

- Fires `onpopstate` on both *real* and *virtual* events
- Seems to **NOT** re-run javascript before the event (so `loaded` will be true if previously set to be true!)

Hopefully I'm just missing something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/).  It should give you an API that behaves consistently across all major platforms (though it's possible that it does not address this specific issue; you'll have to try it to find out).

However, in my opinion, the best way to handle this (and other related issues too) is to design your application in such a way that these issues don't matter. Keep track of your application's state yourself, instead of relying exclusively on the state object in the history stack.

Keep track of what page your application is *currently showing*. Track it in a variable -- separate from `window.location`. When a navigation event (including popstate) arrives, compare your known `current page` to the requested `next page`. Start by figuring out whether or not a page change is actually required.  If so, then render the requested page, and call pushState if necessary (only call pushState for "normal" navigation -- never in response to a popstate event).

The same code that handles popstate, should also handle your normal navigation.  As far as your application is concerned, there should be no difference (except that normal nav includes a call to pushState, while popstate-driven nav does not).

Here's the basic idea in code (see the live example [at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/aberog/1))

```
// keep track of the current page.
var currentPage = null;

// This function will be called every time a navigation
// is requested, whether the navigation request is due to
// back/forward button, or whether it comes from calling
// the `goTo` function in response to a user's click... 
// either way, this function will be called. 
// 
// The argument `pathToShow` will indicate the pathname of
// the page that is being requested. The var `currentPage` 
// will contain the pathname of the currently visible page.
// `currentPage` will be `null` if we're coming in from 
// some other site.
// 
// Don't call `_renderPage(path)` directly.  Instead call
// `goTo(path)` (eg. in response to the user clicking a link
// in your app).
//
function _renderPage(pathToShow) {
  if (currentPage === pathToShow) {
    // if we're already on the proper page, then do nothing.
    // return false to indicate that no actual navigation 
    // happened.
    //
    return false;
  }

  // ...
  // your data fetching and page-rendering 
  // logic goes here
  // ...

  console.log("renderPage");
  console.log("  prev page  : " + currentPage);
  console.log("  next page  : " + pathToShow);

  // be sure to update `currentPage`
  currentPage = pathToShow;

  // return true to indicate that a real navigation
  // happened, and should be stored in history stack
  // (eg. via pushState - see `function goTo()` below).
  return true;
}

// listen for popstate events, so we can handle 
// fwd/back buttons...
//
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(evt) {
  // ask the app to show the requested page
  // this will be a no-op if we're already on the
  // proper page.
  _renderPage(window.location.pathname);
});

// call this function directly whenever you want to perform
// a navigation (eg. when the user clicks a link or button).
// 
function goTo(path) {

  // turn `path` into an absolute path, so it will compare
  // with `window.location.pathname`. (you probably want
  // something a bit more robust here... but this is just 
  // an example).
  //
  var basePath, absPath;
  if (path[0] === '/') {
    absPath = path;
  } else {
    basePath = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    basePath.pop();
    basePath = basePath.join('/');    
    absPath = basePath + '/' + path;
  }

  // now show that page, and push it onto the history stack.
  var changedPages = _renderPage(absPath);
  if (changedPages) {
    // if renderPage says that a navigation happened, then
    // store it on the history stack, so the back/fwd buttons
    // will work.
    history.pushState({}, document.title, absPath);
  }
}

// whenever the javascript is executed (or "re-executed"), 
// just render whatever page is indicated in the browser's 
// address-bar at this time.
//
_renderPage(window.location.pathname);
```

If you check out the [example on jsBin](http://jsbin.com/aberog/1), you'll see that the `_renderPage` function is called every time the app requests a transition to a new page -- whether it's due to `popstate` (eg. back/fwd button), or it's due to calling `goTo(page)` (eg. a user action of some sort).  It's even called when the page first loads.

Your logic, in the `_renderPage` function can use the value of `currentPage` to determine "where the request is coming from". If we're coming from an outside site then `currentPage` will be `null`, otherwise, it will contain the pathname of the currently visible page.

Comment: This is very close, and I'm going to consider it answered. There is more complexity in the way different browsers implement _real_ history states, with Safari doing things very different (and actually much nicer in my particular example) than Chrome and Firefox. If anyone wants to see this in the wild, go [here](http://biologos.org/resources/find), select a few tags, **scroll to the bottom and load another page**, then click a result. Now click the browser back button and notice the difference in Safari – it restores the previous state with ajax-loaded content already in place.

Comment: Thanks. But I think you missed my point a bit. I meant that your code should not be concerned at all with the difference between "real" and "virtual" navigations. Instead, handle *all* navigations based on the two pieces of information that are always available: [a] current state (what page am i on now?), and [b] next state (what page is requested by the event that triggered this navigation?). Handle `popstate` just like any other nav event; and don't depend on info stored in history's state object, base all navigations on the URL only.  Do these things, and browser differences won't matter.

Comment: @MikeMarcacci, An interesting aside: I do see the Safari behavior you described on the [page you linked](http://biologos.org/resources/find). Oddly, I can't duplicate that behavior on [this test page](http://jsbin.com/ebisiw/1/). In that test, when returning from an external site, Safari re-runs the javascript, and fires a popstate event -- same as Chrome.  I suspect that Safari is using some kind of heuristic to decide which approach to follow on a page-by-page basis.  In any case, my recommendations still stand. The code I've shown should work, regardless of how Safari decides to behave.

Comment: I agree with you, and am using the strategy you suggested. In reality, my question was misguided by Safari's unique treatment, which I noticed before trying other browsers. Yours is definitely the proper way to handle such things, and works in all situations. Thanks for the great answer!