# How to update page content when navigating back on all major browsers?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple use-case: *Page1* is a list. When clicking on a list item, user goes to *Page2* where she can make changes to that item. When navigating back, *Page1* should reflect the changes.

Note: *Page1* and *Page2* are different pages for the server (this website is not a single-page webapp).

Disabling cache doesn't seem to solve the issue. Setting the `Cache-Control` header to `no-cache, no-store` works in Firefox (page refreshed upon navigating back), but fails in IE 11, Chrome desktop, Opera desktop, Safari OS X and Safari iOS. Surprisingly, it works on Chrome Android on my device.

I doubt there is a way to have the page refreshed that way on all those browsers, but I'll ask just in case: *Is it possible to have a page consistently reloaded on all major browsers when navigating back?*

If the answer is no, then Javascript may come to the rescue? For example some event(s) that I can listen to, and which will be triggered when navigating back, something that would work on all major browsers.

Basically, any solution where I can have updated data in *Page1* when navigating back.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: I tested the "unload" trick explained at [Is there a cross-browser onload event when clicking the back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button?rq=1), and it doesn't work in Safari on Mac (V7.0.4).

Comment: maybe this helps?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button?rq=1

Comment: @juvian Thanks for that suggestion. I had vaguely tested, with no convincing result. Will test more seriously and update my question.

Comment: @juvian Tested and edited my question. As some others wrote as a comment on that answer, the trick doesn't work in some current browsers.

Comment: The better question is, why would the user **need** to hit the back button? It should be clear on Page2 what the next step is. Navigating back is just not user friendly.

Comment: @beautifulcoder I use the back button _all the time_ — rather than using a 'home' button to get 'back' to the app home by going forward (in browser history) to start a new task I drop-down the history and jump to where I want to be. It may be not-the-usual behavior, but an app should handle that.

Comment: Well, not sure as I do not have safari, but there seem to be several topics about this, but doubt there is a cross-browser solution unless you try to use plugins. Maybe try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257819/onpopstate-handler-ajax-back-button . Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172957/detecting-back-button-hash-change-in-url?rq=1

Comment: @juvian Both the popstate event and hash change are useful for navigation in the same document (i.e single-page websites). As mentioned in my question, my website uses a classic architecture (*Page1* and *Page2* are different documents)

Comment: @Blackbird Well, first you need to check if you are able to detect browse back button on Page 1 with some of those options or another. Then you can do some localstorage changing in Page1 and listen for that in Page2 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236828/javascript-communication-between-tabs-windows-with-same-origin/12514384#12514384

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in the HTML?

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

Why dont you just Redirect to Page1 after the user commits his changes on Page2 so that the user doesnt even have to go back in Browser?

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, even with this header added, the page doesn't reload when navigating back on Safari OS X.